# x86: Access writing violation while using the OFFSET operator to address of array

Tags: exception, assembly, x86

I am getting the Exception thrown at 0x0044369D in Project2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000099. From my research so far, I am under the impression this has to do with a null pointer or out of range memory being accessed from the line `mov [eax], ecx`

I used the offset operator in `mov eax, OFFSET arrayfib` and I thought that should remedy this. I can't seem to figure out what is causing the issue here.

```
.model flat, stdcall 
.stack 4096
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode: DWORD

.data
arrayfib DWORD 35 DUP (99h)


.code 
main PROC   
    mov eax, OFFSET arrayfib    ;address of fibonacci number array 
    mov bx, 30                  ;number of Fibonacci numbers to generate
    call fibSequence            ;call to Fibonacci sequence procedure 
    mov edx, OFFSET arrayfib    ;passes information to call DumpMem
    mov ecx, LENGTHOF arrayfib
    mov ebx, TYPE arrayfib 
    call DumpMem

    INVOKE ExitProcess, 0 
main ENDP
;----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;fibSequence
;Calculates the fibonacci numbers to the n'th fibonacci number 
;Receives: eax = address of the Fibonacci number array
;bx = number of Fibonacci numbers to generate
;ecx = used for Fibonacci calculation (i-2)
;edx = used for Fibonacci calculation (i-1)
;returns: [eax+4i] = each value of fibonacci sequence in array, scaled for doubleword
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

fibSequence PROC                    
    mov ecx, 0                  ;initialize the registers with Fib(0) and Fib(1)
    mov edx, 1      
    mov [eax], edx              ;store first Fibonacci number in the array 
                                ;since a Fibonacci number has been generated, decrement the counter
                                ;test for completion, proceed
    mov eax, [eax+4]

fibLoop: 
    sub bx, 1
    jz quit                     ;if bx = 0, jump to exit
    add ecx, edx
    push ecx                    ;save fib# for next iteration before it is destroyed
    mov [eax], ecx              ;stores new fibonacci number in the next address of array 
    push edx                    ;save other fib# before it is destroyed
    mov ecx, edx
    mov edx, [eax]
    mov eax, [eax+4]            ;increments accounting for doubleword 
    pop edx
    pop ecx 
quit: 
    exit
fibSequence ENDP
END main
```

Also if there are any other suggestions I would be happy to hear them. I am new to all this and looking to learn as much as possible.

Comment: Your problem  is `mov eax, [eax+4]`. That is a load from memory. You probably wanted `add eax, 4` instead. PS: learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Alternatively you can use `lea eax, [eax+4]` which is the same as `add eax, 4`.

Comment: @Jester I know how to use the debugger but I believe there is a bug in VS 2019 which says  “Edits were made which cannot be compiled…” every time I try to use the debugger..which is a whole other issue. It does it every time it hits a breakpoint :/

Comment: However, it worked. Thank you for catching my silly error

Comment: That debug error sounds like you're editing while you're still debugging (edit-and-continue).  You need to stop debugging then recompile.